# Move specified JSON object from array to a different array

Tags: json, bash, sed, jq

I have hundreds of files formatted like this:

```
{
    "settings": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "value": "A_value"
        },
        {
            "name": "B",
            "value": "B_value"
        },
        {
            "name": "C",
            "value": "C_value"
        },
        {
            "name": "D",
            "value": "D_value"
        }
    ]
}
```

and need to modifiy them by taking some of names and values to another array but only the specific ones for e.g. B and D so the file will look like:

```
{
    "settings": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "value": "A_value"
        },
        {
            "name": "C",
            "value": "C_value"
        }
    ],
    "settings2": [
        {
            "name": "B",
            "value": "B_value"
        },
        {
            "name": "D",
            "value": "D_value"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can it be done in a bash script? I have a list of "names" that have to be moved.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?  What obstacles have you encountered?

Comment: Where does the name "settings2" come from?  Please align your explanation, the sample input, and the sample output more clearly. You might find the [mcve] guidelines helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
to_move='["B", "D"]'
jq --argjson toMove "$to_move" '{
    "settings":  [.settings[] | select([.name] | inside($toMove) | not)],
    "settings2": [.settings[] | select([.name] | inside($toMove))]
}' file.json
```

```
{
  "settings": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "value": "A_value"
    },
    {
      "name": "C",
      "value": "C_value"
    }
  ],
  "settings2": [
    {
      "name": "B",
      "value": "B_value"
    },
    {
      "name": "D",
      "value": "D_value"
    }
  ]
}
```